# Mongodb Query giving error: Expression $gt takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am writting the following query to retrive the records based on 2 conditions.Executing the Query giving me error:

```
> db.employee.find({age:{$lt:32}},{salary:{$lt:40000}})
```

Here is the error Message:

```
Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Expression $lt takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.",
        "code" : 16020,
        "codeName" : "Location16020"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To do a find query based in two conditions, you need to do in the same query object.

Note that you are doing:

```
find({obj1},{obj2}
```

But second parameter into find method is for projection ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/))

So you need this query:

```
db.collection.find({
  "age": {
    "$lt": 32
  },
  "salary": {
    "$lt": 40000
  }
})
```

Note how there is only one object with two fields: `age` and `salary`.
Something like `find( { age:{}, salary:{}} )`.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mFO80rOaoVW)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to implement AND condition.
You have to write all the conditions in the single object clause {} and separate the conditions by a comma.
Like:

```
db.employee.find({ age:{$lt:32}, salary:{$lt:40000}});
```